Probability of committing a type I error
Let $X_1, ... ,X_n$ be an iid sample from the Bern(p) distribution, with $p \in (0, 1)$. I want to test the null hypothesis $H_0: p = \frac{1}{2}$ against the alternative $H_1: p \in (0, 1) \setminus $ {$ \frac{1}{2} $} using the test statistic
$T_n(X_1, ..., X_n) = \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n X_i - \frac{1}{2}$
and the corresponding test function: $\delta(X_1, ..., X_n) = 1$, if $|T_n(X_1, ..., X_n)| \geq Q$ [and = 0, otherwise]
where $Q \in (0, \frac{1}{2} ]$.
How can I compute the probability of committing a type I error?

There term 'type I error' is used everywhere but is always incorrect as this has nothing to do with an error.  An error would be for example concluding that an effect is positive when it turns out that the effect is nil, i.e., would have an error probability Pr(true effect = 0 given we think it's > 0).  That's why I call this type I assertion probability $\alpha$ as detailed here.  It's nothing more than the probability of making an assertion of an effect when all effect assertions are by definition false.

Probability of $p=1/2$ is zero. $p$ is a continuous variable, albeit on finite domain, so probability of it taking any precise value is zero. You can ask whether $p$ is in some finite-sized range, e.g. is $p \in \left(0.45, 0.55\right)$. That could be finite.
Using beta distribution you can actually estimate the probability distribution for your $p$, given data.
If you really want to stay in frequentist paradigm, nothing stops you from generating a bunch of random samples, computing your test statistic for them and getting empirical distribution for your test statistic under the null-hypothesis. From there you should be able to read off the probability of type-I directly (the amount of probability distribution that lies in the range where you would reject the null).
If you wanted to go analytic, I would probably note that:
$$
\sum_{i=1}^n X_i\sim Binomial(n,p)
$$
So your test statistic is linearly related to a binomial random variable. So you could compute the the probability of test statistic lying in the reject-null region analytically (in this case)

Probability of p = 1/2 is zero According to what distribution?

@Dave If p is the probability of a Bernoulli distribution, it is a continuous variable. The probability of a continuous variable to be equal to a fixed real number has to be zero, or you will not be able to have a sensible probability density for $p$

Why do you say $p$ must be continuous? Why does $p$ have any distribution at all?

@Dave, to me this is clear from the context of $p$ being the parameter of the Bernoulli distribution. I nevertheless, state this explicitly in the second sentence

Why does $p$ have to have a distribution? I think the distribution of $p$ is not crucial here, my statement is true for any distribution where $p$ is continuous. What I wanted to highlight was that setting up the null and alternative hypothesis the way it was done in OP means that no amount of data will be enough to distinguish H1 and H0. One may be able to reject H0, but data will never be improbable under H1. Not the best setup

"Probability of $p$" is meaningless in a NHST framework, because $p$ is not modeled as a random variable.  "Probability of Type I error" is meaningful, because it refers to the event of rejecting $H_0$ when $H_0$ holds and $H_0$ is a simple hypothesis (implying this probability is unique).

@whuber, I am not saying that you cannot do hypothesis testing with $p=1/2$. You can, it's simply a bit shallow. Let's say I reject null, data is not consistent with $p=0.5$, but could be consistent with 0.501, but is such difference important? So yes you can condition on a very improbable case of $p=1/2$ and try to extract inference from likelihood of a statistic, but it might be better to build on more solid foundation

The problem here is that when you make an meaningless assertion, you're not saying anything.

@whuber, please read beyond the first sentence. I suggest a better way to frame the hypothesis, then suggest using beta distribution, then suggest empirical approach, the suggest using connection to binomial distribution

The reason I make assertion is to motivate a better way of framing the null hypothesis. The way it is framed right now means that data is always consistent with the alternative hypothesis, so it is not that good of an alternative
